# How do i magento2 migrate setting from from magento 1.9.0.1 to magento2.2.6 , I am using CE and working on windows machine wamp server

Tags: magento2.2, migration, magento2-migration-tool

i am new to magento
[image]using the below command and got the issue as below

E:\wamp\www\magento226>php bin\magento migrate:setting -r vendor\magento\data-migration-tool\etc\opensourse-to-opensourse\1.9.0.1\config.xml

[Migration\Exception]
  Invalid config filename: vendor\magento\data-migration-tool\etc\opensourse-to-opensourse\1.9.0.1\config.xml

migrate:settings [-r|--reset] [-a|--auto] [--]

And generally in the tutorials can able see in the etc folder ce-to-ce, ce-to-ee and ee-to-ee, but here in my machine i can see commerce-to-commerce,opensource-to-commerce and opensource-to-opensource

[image]

Comment: did you change the config.xml file name in this location`vendor\magento\data-migration-tool\etc\opensourse-to-opensourse\1.9.0.1\` from `config.xml.dist` to `config.xml` ?

Comment: did you try with full path like this? 
`E:\wamp\www\magento226>php bin\magento migrate:setting -r E:\wamp\www\magento226\vendor\magento\data-migration-tool\etc\opensourse-to-opensourse\1.9.0.1\config.xml`

Comment: tried with your suggestion ,but result is same

Comment: if possible upload screenshot of your directory structure and files in this location `\wamp\www\magento226\vendor\magento\data-migration-tool\etc\opensourse-to-opensourse\1.9.0.1\`

Comment: Thanks Rakesh for the quick comment , just added the image for folder structure

Answer (score 1):

there is a mistake in spelling
its not **opensourse** its **opensource**

try this

```
E:\wamp\www\magento226>php bin\magento migrate:setting -r vendor\magento\data-migration-tool\etc\opensource-to-opensource\1.9.0.1\config.xml
```

Comment: its working now , Thanks for ur reply Rakesh

Comment: Welcome. Accept answer if its help you